# I require Express 3.x for my project but after installing I keep getting ' express --version 1.4.28'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm, version

I have tried many things. Uninstalling npm and express.
Following this thread: [Node.js npm install express error fetch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435222/node-js-npm-install-express-error-fetch-failed)
Can someone explain what I am not doing Incorrectly.
I know this is simple and I have resolved this in other circumstances but this will not resolve.

```
package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "~0.0.3",
    "consolidate": "~0.9.1",
    "express": ">=3.2.6",
    "mongodb": "~1.4.34",
etc.
```

At prompt if I do 'npm install' I thought it would use the version listed in the dependency list but it installed express 4.0.  see below.

```
> npm install
```

Shouldn't that install the versions in the dependency list ?

Express 4.0; it is not compatible with my course.  4.x is the default at this point in time.

```
>npm install express
npm express --version
4.0

>rm -rf express
>which express
(returns nothing)

>npm install express@3.2.6


>npm express --version
1.4.28
```

I think 1.4.28 is the version of npm itself.
What is going on please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, you're looking at the npm version.  To see the version of your installed packages use

```
npm ls
```

or for express only

```
npm ls express
```

Comment: thanks.  Here is the output.  
macbookpro:blog myname$ npm ls express
blog@0.0.0 /Users/mynamel/Desktop/week2/homework_2_3/hw2-3/hw2-3/blog
└── express@3.2.6    
But why is 'npm express --version'  telling me the version of npm - 'not the version of express'.    
Wouldn't i do 'npm npm --version' to see the version of npm ?

Comment: The command to see the version of npm is npm --version.  When you type npm express --version it doesn't understand the express command so it just falls back to npm --version.  Try with npm blahblahblah --version and you will see the same thing.  You can see the full list of npm commands with npm --help.  The npm command is a binary, not an a node module, though it will call the globally installed npm package (confusing I know).  To see your globally installed npm version you can use npm -g ls npm

Comment: @ dskh Thank you Again.  Great clarification !